# Youtube video plays automatically when Bluetooth headphones switch

Tags: sound, bluetooth, google-chrome, headphones, youtube

When my Bluetooth headphones are connected to both my laptop and my phone, and I am on a phone call, when the phone call ends, a Youtube video that was paused in a tab in my laptop's Chrome browser automatically starts playing and I hear it on the Bluetooth headphones.

Ubuntu 22.04, Android Pixel 7, Youtube autoplay turned off.

I don't want Youtube videos playing on my laptop unless I press the play button. Any ideas where I may control this? Thank you.

Comment: I have seen the same issue on my Windows 11 computer and would love to know if you found out why that happens and how to stop it

Comment: I'll update this if I ever do.